# Javascript not working within a view but works in the rest of the views in the application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a view which is referencing a Javascript file which contains an Auto Complete function.  The problem is in this view the Javascript is not working at all. Even an alert on document.ready will not work.  I can use the exact javascript file in a different view and it works perfectly.   I do not know what is wrong with the following view.

**VIEW**

```
   @model RunLog.Domain.Entities.ErrorCode
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter a new Error Code</legend>@*<div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Error ID")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID)
            </span>
        </div>*@
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Error Description")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ErrorDescription, new { style = "width: 500px;" })
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Parent ID")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.DropDownList("ParentID", String.Empty)
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Error Description Complete")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ErrorDescriptionWithParent, new { style = "width:500px;" })
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("High Level Error")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.highlevelerror, new { style = "width:500px;" })
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Error Number")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ErrorNumber)
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Track")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.track)
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Lane")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lane)
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Subsystem")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.subsystem, new { id = "rootcause" })
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Critical")
            </span><span class="rightContent">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.critical)
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent"></span><span class="rightContent">
                <input id="create" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Create" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "List")
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var serviceRootCauseUrl = '@Url.Action("FindRootCause", "ServiceEntry")';
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/rootcause.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**JAVASCRIPT FILE**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#rootcause").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: serviceRootCauseUrl, type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                minLength: 0,
                data: { searchText: request.term, maxResult: 100 },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.FullName, value: item.RootCauseName, id: item.ID }
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            //                $("#rootcause").text(selecteditem.text);
            //                alert(ui.item ? ("You picked '" + ui.item.label + "' with an ID of " + ui.item.id)
            //                            : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

**LAYOUT FILE**

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/style.css")" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/style.ie6.css")" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/style.ie7.css")" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/main.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/Content.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/jquery.treeview.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.treeview.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/scrolltable.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/grid.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/datetime.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Your file is included in view. Are you sure its not getting loaded? Do you see it in console resources or do you get an 404 error?

Comment: Artyom I am testing this on Safari. I do have Firefox. How could I determine correctly in the console resources?

Comment: even the document.ready function is not working. A simple alert will also not display

Comment: In Firefox press `Ctrl+Shift+K` and check if there are any errors.

Comment: I am getting a few css error but no JS errors. Not sure why it will still not show alert in the JS function

Comment: Do you include jQuery script?

Comment: @user20140268  which one?

Comment: Your code depends on `jquery` but I don't see it in your `view`. Does it present in `shared/_layout.cshtml`? If not try to paste `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` before other scripts.

Comment: I posted my code for the layout file.  There problem is the jquery auto complete works in a different view just fine. it could be a path issue to the rootcause file?